# Code editor compatibility with Sitecore 9.3

Tags: content-editor

We have used the Code editor market place module to edit CSS, Less & JS in Sitecore 8.1 content editor, this module downloaded from [the marketplace](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Code_Editor.aspx). It was working perfectly fine in our old Sitecore 8.1 version thanks to Michael West.
Now we are in the process of migrating our solution to Sitecore 9.3 and facing issue

> (Method not found: 'Boolean PageMode.get_IsPageEditorEditing()')

this issue due to obsolete methods in the new version of Sitecore.
is there anyone who faced a similar issue? how you overcome this? did you find an alternate solution (or) any upgraded module?

Thanks for reading, looking for your input. hope Michael West can provide a better answer for this.

Comment: It looks like this module is no longer maintained, but you could try take the source from the latest branch and build it against Sitecore 9.3 https://github.com/michaellwest/sitecore-codeeditor/tree/release/v3.0.0

Comment: I will try this. Thankyou  Mark Gibbons!!!

Comment: Pull requests are welcomed!